# How to query routes in here maps with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, heremaps

I am trying to make map queries with here maps on routes with reactjs, currently I can display the map in my application with this code:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const DisplayMapFC = () => {
  // Create a reference to the HTML element we want to put the map on
  const mapRef = React.useRef(null);

  /**
   * Create the map instance
   * While `useEffect` could also be used here, `useLayoutEffect` will render
   * the map sooner
   */
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // `mapRef.current` will be `undefined` when this hook first runs; edge case that
    if (!mapRef.current) return;
    const H = window.H;
    const platform = new H.service.Platform({
        apikey: "xxxxxxxxx"
    });
    
    const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    const hMap = new H.Map(mapRef.current, defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
      center: { lat: 36.2104063, lng: -113.7236071 }, //,
      zoom: 4,
      pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
    });


    const behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(hMap));

    const ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(hMap, defaultLayers);

    // This will act as a cleanup to run once this hook runs again.
    // This includes when the component un-mounts
    return () => {
      hMap.dispose();
    };
  }, [mapRef]); // This will run this hook every time this ref is updated

  return <div className="map" ref={mapRef} style={{ height: "355px",width:"650px" }} />;
};


const searchMap=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(" view controle ",e);
    const origin="52.5308,13.3847";
    const destiny="52.5264,13.3686";
}
```

I am trying to send coordinates from a start point to an end point so that I can show the plotted route and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me:
Change API_KEY, origin and destination. Luck!
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-with-heremap-2cze0?file=/src/mapHere.js